# How to use node-webkit-agent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, node-webkit-agent

How to use [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent)?

I'm stuck with the second step:
`Using your browser, go to devtools frontend URL corresponding to your nodejs version`

How can I access the devtools?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the readme, you will probably want the 0.8 url below...

### Conecting to the agent

Nodejs v0.6.x

http://c4milo.github.com/node-webkit-agent/19.0.1084.46/inspector.html?host=localhost:1337&page=0

Nodejs v0.8.x

http://c4milo.github.com/node-webkit-agent/21.0.1180.57/inspector.html?host=localhost:1337&page=0

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/webkit-devtools-agent-frontend

You can host your own front-end for it, by npm-install'ing this.

`npm install -g webkit-devtools-agent-frontend`

When you run your app, send SIGUSR2 and restart (which im currently running into errors with), open up a second terminal and run command `webkit-devtools-agent-frontend` it will display the port number it is running on for you to view in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The README has the URLs, those are copies of devtools frontend. You could also checkout the gh-pages branch and open any of them locally